# VBA- Extracting Text from DIV where no CLASS, ID, TAG

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the Script

```
<div style="padding-left:0em; margin:10px 25px 24px 0px;">
  <div style='word-wrap:break-word; max-height:50px; overflow:hidden;'>                 
    <a style="display:unset; font-size:1.25em;" href="http://www.aptcenter.research.va.gov/staff/investigators/zhu/">Hui Zhu, MD, ScD - Advanced Platform Technology <b>Center</b></a>
  </div>

  <div class="url" style='word-spacing:normal; word-wrap:break-word; color:#008933; margin-bottom:2px; margin-top:2px'>
        www.aptcenter.research.va.gov/&#8203;staff/&#8203;investigators/&#8203;zhu
  </div>
  <div style='color:#545454; line-height:1.3em; word-wrap:break-word; margin-bottom:2px;'>Jewish Hospital. Fellowship training took place in Urological Oncology at the <b>Memorial</b> <b>Sloan</b>-<b>Kettering</b> <b>Cancer</b> <b>Center</b> in New York <b>Center</b>. Dr. Zhu</div>
    <div class='no-print' style='margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:4px; color:#010101;'>                   
        View results from <a href="/search/va/va_search.jsp?QT=Memorial+Sloan+Kettering+Cancer+Center&amp;SQ=www.aptcenter.research.va.gov&amp;DB=3">APTCENTER RESEARCH</a>         
        or related <a href="/search/va/va_search.jsp?QT=Memorial+Sloan+Kettering+Cancer+Center&amp;DB=3">Health Research</a> sites
    </div>                  
  </div>
```

I want to get Title i.e. "Hui Zhu, MD, ScD - Advanced Platform Technology Center" and then Text below link i.e. "Jewish Hospital. Fellowship training took place in Urological Oncology at the Memorial Sloan-Kettering Cancer Center in New York Center. Dr. Zhu"

Here is my current code

```
Dim objIE As Object, Slink As String
Dim hUls As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim httpRequest As XMLHTTP
Dim divElem As HTMLDivElement

Set httpRequest = New XMLHTTP

Slink = "https://www.index.va.gov/search/va/va_search.jsp?QT=Memorial+Sloan+Kettering+Cancer+Center&RS=1"

With httpRequest
    .Open "GET", Slink, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send
End With
With httpRequest
    While Not .readyState = 4
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
    Wend
    If .Status = 200 Then
        While InStr(1, .responseText, "Updating", 0) > 0
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
        Wend
        Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument
        oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End If
End With

Set divElem = oHtml.getElementById("innerContent")
MsgBox divElem.getAttribute("padding-left:0em; margin:10px 25px 24px 0px;").cssText
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: Edited now with my code also.

Comment: Oh that page, will you want to return **all* the people and descriptions, or just the first one in the results?

Comment: All the results Bruce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a little tweaking, and assuming the HTML doesn't really change, but this should help you out.

It will return an array at the end that has the "link" text and the "body" text that describes the link.

Remove `Set divElem` and after...and replace with this:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim title() As Variant
ReDim title(0)

Dim ele As Object

Set aElem = oHtml.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each ele In aElem
    If ele.Style = "FONT-SIZE" Then ' Will return each of the search findings main info
        title(UBound(title)) = ele.innerText
        ReDim Preserve title(LBound(title) To UBound(title) + 1)
    End If
Next ele

Dim text() As Variant
ReDim text(0)

Set divElem = oHtml.getElementsByTagName("div")
For Each ele In divElem
    If ele.getAttribute("style").cssText = "WORD-WRAP: break-word; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 2px; COLOR: #545454; LINE-HEIGHT: 1.3em" Then
        text(UBound(text)) = ele.innerText
        ReDim Preserve text(LBound(text) To UBound(text) + 1)
    End If
Next ele

Dim combinedInfo() As Variant
ReDim combinedInfo(UBound(title), 1)
For i = LBound(title) To UBound(title)
    combinedInfo(i, 0) = title(i)
    combinedInfo(i, 1) = text(i)
Next i

For i = LBound(title) To UBound(title) - 1
    Debug.Print combinedInfo(i, 0) & " ::: " & combinedInfo(i, 1)
Next i

End Sub
```

The `combinedInfo` array has the Link Text as the `(i,0)`  index, and the Link description is the `(i,1)` index.

It's a little clunky, but if it works, you can just refactor into separate functions (one for the `a` tags and one for the `div` tags perhaps), but it worked for me with what you gave.

Comment: Thanks a Ton Bruce.